# How to programmatically get Azure Service Bus Relay details (C#)?

Tags: c#, azure, service, relay, bus

I need to know following details about Azure SB-Relay:

> - Is relay exists?
> - No of listeners
> - Other details

I tried:

```
var nsmgr = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString("....");
bool b = nsmgr.RelayExists("SubjectedRelayName");
```

However, b is always false even though Relays exists in the list.

Can you please help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of Service Bus SDK are you using? I couldn't find RelayExists method. All I could find was RelayExistsAsync.

Comment: Hello Gaurav, version no is v4.0.30319 and it has also "RelayExists" (Sync version).

Comment: Thanks. I just tried this and I was able to run it properly. What is the name you're giving for relay name? It should be path of the relay relative to the service namespace base address.

Comment: Hi. Interesting. Here is what I use for "RelayExists()" mehod parameter. For example, the name of my relay in the Azure portal is "testrelay/service.svc"
and I tried both:
RelayExists("https://myrelaysns.servicebus.windows.net/testrelay/service.svc") = returns "false" always
and 
RelayExists("testrelay/service.svc") = always crashes with "Accepted" httpstatus code.

Comment: This is what I used:             `var manager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString("my connection string");
            var b = manager.RelayExists("temp");
            Console.WriteLine(b);`. I get `True` back.

Comment: Ok. Is that "Temp" what you see in the Azure portal-->ServiceBus-->Relay as relay name?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: For me, if I use only relay name in the parameter, I get exception. but if, I use whole path, I get false always. I really do not know what is causing this. Is there any other way to get relay details? REST-API?